# Why my recursive code is giving sigsegv error?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

> Given an array of non-negative integers arr, you are initially positioned at start index of the array. When you are at index `i`, you can jump to `i + arr[i]` or `i - arr[i]`, check if you can reach to any index with value 0. (Return true or false).

```
Input: arr = [4,2,3,0,3,1,2], start = 5
Output: true
```

> Explanation: index 5 -> index 4 -> index 1 -> index 3
>
> index 5 -> index 6 -> index 4 -> index 1 -> index 3
>
> Notice that you can not jump outside of the array at any time.

```
class Solution 
{
  public:
    bool canReach(vector<int>& arr, int start) 
    {
        if(start<0 || start>=arr.size())
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(arr[start]==0)
        {
            return true;            
        }
        bool x = canReach( arr,  start+arr[start]);
        bool y = canReach( arr,  start-arr[start]);
        return (x||y);
    }
};
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Please post code that actually fails as is.

Comment: Probably running out of stack space. Don't make the 2nd recursive call if the first returns true. You can end up in cycles that way.

Comment: Yes ,I  need to break the cycle using memoization or visited array  so that it doesnot visit again ,thank you

Comment: Before jump to i + arr[i] or i - arr[i]; you check the index out of bound.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a case where the input vector is arr = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1} and start = 1.According to you code, in this case, there will be an infinite number of recursive calls to the function.
This can be understood as:
if we are at index 1 and do start - arr[i] we reach index 0. Then if we do start + arr[i] we again reach index 1. This leads to an infinite number of calls to the function.

index 1 -> index 0 -> index 1 -> index 0 -> index 1-> so on.

Since recursion uses stack, this may lead to stack-overflow, thus aborting the function execution.

One way to handle this case is to use an unordered_set to store the indecies which have been visited earlier. If we have visited an index earlier than we should simply return false because there is no way that it can return true now.
Here is the implementation you can try:

```
unordered_set<int> s;
bool canReach(vector<int>& arr, int start) {

    if(start<0 || start>=arr.size() || (s.find(start) != s.end()))
        return false;
    if(arr[start]==0)
        return true;            
    s.insert(start);
    bool x = canReach( arr,  start+arr[start]);
    bool y = canReach( arr,  start-arr[start]);
    return (x||y);
}
```

It should work.

Comment: An unordered_set is overkill.  We know that the indicies visited will be between 0 and size(arr).   So a simple vector of flags using the same indicies is enough.
Also, having a global state variable is problematic for a few reasons, namely, it function only works on the first call.  But it's also not thread safe, etc.  A better approach would be 2 functions, the first creates a local vector (proper size) which then calls into the recursive function, returning its result.  The recursive function is not called by anyone else, and sets the vector element _i_ true when v[i] is visited.